# Cannot convert string to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

So, i am creating a service (using ASP.NETCore 3.1) that receives information about the operation schedule of a shop that can be registered in the system. For that i have an entity which communicates to the database and a model which communicates with this entity, as follows:

Entity:

```
public class OperationSchedule
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Open { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Close { get; set; }
        public DayOfWeek DatofWeek { get; set; }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class OperationScheduleModel
    {
        public TimeSpan Open { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Close { get; set; }
        public DayOfWeek DatofWeek { get; set; }
    }
```

Of course they were already mapped using automapper. I'm using swagger to test such communications. The problem begins when i try to post a new "operation schedule", swagger shows me the following output:

Error converting value "string" to type 'System.TimeSpan'

In my first attemption to resolve this problem i'd tryied to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, and configured it in startup this way: `services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

As long it does not resolved my problem i was thinking in map the types string and TimeSpan on Automapper by doing something like this:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {            
            // Custom types mapping
            CreateMap<string, TimeSpan>.ConvertUsing<StringToTimeSpanConverter>();

            // OperationSchedule mapping
            CreateMap<OperationSchedule, OperationScheduleModel>();
            CreateMap<OperationScheduleModel, OperationSchedule>();
        }
    }
```

But VisualStudio isn't letting me do so, saying that a cannot use "StringToTimeSpanConverter" as a generic property, something like `ConvertUsing(new StringToTimeSpanConverter());` doesn't make any difference.
I really can't even imagine another way to resolve it, but may i missing something? Help please

Comment: For your Automapper issue, you'd need to pass a `Func` or an `ITypeConverter<S,D>`.  See method signature `void ConvertUsing(ITypeConverter<TSource, TDestination> converter);`.

Comment: This is a built in conversion in AM, so normally you don't need a type converter. But that's considering only the AM part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error converting value "string" to type 'System.TimeSpan'

The reason for this is that `System.Text.Json` doesn't support TimeSpan.

One solution is to go back to `JSON.NET`. Here are the steps:

Add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`.

Update `Startup.ConfigureServices` to call `AddNewtonsoftJson`.

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Another option is to use a custom converter for that TimeSpan:

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter<TimeSpan>
{
    public override TimeSpan Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();
        return TimeSpan.Parse(value);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TimeSpan value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Register it in `Startup.ConfigureServices` with `AddJsonOptions`:

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter())
);
```

Result:
[image]